# How to calculate "karma" in a social network with polymorphic tables?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm writing some social capabilities inside my application. Kind of like what you have in reddit, where a user gets upvotes and downvotes on messages and comments, and that is used to calculate "karma". I'm opting for something basic, so I have the following models:

```
User
Message
Comment
Vote
```

All the relations are in set, and they are working (ie. `User HasMany Message`; `Comment BelongsTo Message`, and such)

Then `Vote` is a polymorphic table with its relations set. It has a `vote` attribute which can be `1` or `-1`, so you're upvoting or downvoting. It also stores voting `user_id` and the relation is correctly set.

Now, my problem is... how do I calculate "karma" using these relations?

My first guess was something like:

```
$user = User::find(...);
$karma = $user->messages()->votes()->sum('vote');
```

But of course didn't work. My logic here was getting all the messages for the user, then all the votes those messages had and then sum vote, of course, this didn't work.

So what I did to solve my problem was:

```
$user = User::find(...)
$ids = $user->messages->pluck('id')->toArray();
$karma = Vote::where('voteable_type', 'App\Models\Message')
    ->whereIn('voteable_id', $ids)
    ->sum('vote');
```

And works... I plan to do the same for the comments. But I don't really like my solution. Is it a way to make it cleaner using only relations?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but depending on how frequently karma updates and how frequently it's read, it might benefit to store the total karma in a field ( keep your current votes table as is so that it can be used to recalculate, this field is just for quick read speeds ). If you need to read karma alot, and it updates less frequently, you could recalculate it whenever there is an update and save it to a db field. So you'd keep a karma field on messages and users table. It may sound dirty, but for larger applications, these are a common practice

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that solution too but for other purposes, I have a "competition" where the users get some points, and that logic is more complex, so I add their points on the insert/update/delete instead of on a big query... You're right with test data this is pretty fast and simple, but scaling it might not... I'll give a thought abou it, thanks!